# Apache Storm/Kafka- Storm and Kafka not communicating

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

thank you for your time. I'm attempting to set up an Apache storm/Kafka integration demo. I am able to set up a Kafka cluster and Storm cluster. I am able to run a working topology in Local mode. However, the same topology does not work when I submit it to the cluster.

The Kafka spout in the topology does not emit Tuples, though I didn't change anything major when I brought it from a local mode to the cluster.
The most likely issue would seem to be that Storm and Kafka simply aren't speaking to each other. I've been over my configuration and can't seem to find the point of failure. Zookeeper, Kafka, Storm Nimbus, Storm supervisor, and Kafka Producer are all running on the same machine.

One thing that seems suspicious- I am not able to view executor logs through the Storm UI. I can view Nimbus logs by clicking on the port number, but the executor logs will not do the same when I go into the topology and click on the executor port. Could it have something to do with network security and my port numbers? I've tried monkeying with the port numbers in storm.yaml to no result. In addition, I've rebuilt the entire project and environment on an entirely new machine on a different network. Something must be wrong with my configuration.

Thank you so much! I have to hand this proof-of-concept project off to another developer, because I've been spinning my wheels on this issue all week.

Here is my topology:

```
public class KafkaStormIntegrationDemo {


public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException, AlreadyAliveException {

    // Build Spout configuration using input command line parameters
    final BrokerHosts zkrHosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
    final String kafkaTopic = "storm-kafka";
    final String zkRoot = "";
    final String clientId = "storm-consumer";
    SpoutConfig kafkaConf = new SpoutConfig(zkrHosts, kafkaTopic, zkRoot,clientId);
    kafkaConf.startOffsetTime = -2;
    kafkaConf.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());

    // Build topology to consume message from kafka and print them on console
    final TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();
    topologyBuilder.setSpout("kafka-spout", new KafkaSpout(kafkaConf), 1);
    topologyBuilder.setBolt("print-messages", new
    LoggerBolt()).globalGrouping("kafka-spout");
    Config conf = new Config();
    System.setProperty("storm.jar","C://workspace/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/storm-core-1.1.1.jar");
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology("kafkaTopology", conf,
    topologyBuilder.createTopology());
}
}
```

Here is my bolt:

```
public class LoggerBolt extends BaseBasicBolt{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoggerBolt.class);

public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    LOG.info(input.getString(0));
}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("message"));
}
}
```

here is my storm.yaml:

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
 storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "localhost"
#     - "server2"
# 
 nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]
```

Here are my Executor logs when I call storm supervisor (my PC's name has been censored):

```
2017-10-11 17:26:20.552 o.a.s.z.Zookeeper main [INFO] Staring ZK Curator
2017-10-11 17:26:20.563 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl main [INFO]
Starting
2017-10-11 17:26:20.579 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
2017-10-11 17:26:20.580 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:host.name=[MY PC NAME]
2017-10-11 17:26:20.580 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:java.version=1.8.0_131
2017-10-11 17:26:20.581 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2017-10-11 17:26:20.582 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:java.home=C:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
2017-10-11 17:26:20.582 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:java.class.path=C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\*;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\conf;C:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_131\lib\tools.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\asm-5.0.3.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\clojure-1.7.0.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\disruptor-3.3.2.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\kryo-3.0.3.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\log4j-api-2.8.2.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\log4j-core-2.8.2.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\minlog-1.3.0.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\objenesis-2.1.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\reflectasm-1.10.1.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\ring-cors-0.1.5.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\storm-core-1.1.1.jar;C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\lib\storm-rename-hack-1.1.1.jar
2017-10-11 17:26:20.582 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib;C:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_131\lib;C:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin;C:\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib
2017-10-11 17:26:20.582 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\rbliton\AppData\Local\Temp\
2017-10-11 17:26:20.582 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2017-10-11 17:26:20.582 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:os.name=Windows 10
2017-10-11 17:26:20.583 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:os.arch=amd64
2017-10-11 17:26:20.583 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:os.version=10.0
2017-10-11 17:26:20.583 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:user.name=rbliton
2017-10-11 17:26:20.583 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:user.home=C:\Users\rbliton
2017-10-11 17:26:20.583 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Client
environment:user.dir=C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\bin
2017-10-11 17:26:20.585 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Initiating
client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=20000
watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@2216effc
2017-10-11 17:26:20.801 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn main-SendThread(
127.0.0.1:2181) [INFO] Opening socket connection to server
127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL
(unknown error)
2017-10-11 17:26:20.803 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn main-SendThread(
127.0.0.1:2181) [INFO] Socket connection established to
127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2017-10-11 17:26:20.826 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn main-SendThread(
127.0.0.1:2181) [INFO] Session establishment complete on server
127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x15f0d3b46a70016, negotiated timeout
= 20000
2017-10-11 17:26:20.845 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager
main-EventThread [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2017-10-11 17:26:20.856 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl
Curator-Framework-0 [INFO] backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
2017-10-11 17:26:20.867 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Session:
0x15f0d3b46a70016 closed
2017-10-11 17:26:20.869 o.a.s.z.Zookeeper main [INFO] Staring ZK Curator
2017-10-11 17:26:20.870 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl main [INFO]
Starting
2017-10-11 17:26:20.869 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn main-EventThread [INFO]
EventThread shut down
2017-10-11 17:26:20.870 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper main [INFO] Initiating
client connection, connectString=localhost:2181/storm sessionTimeout=20000
watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@4417af13
2017-10-11 17:26:20.880 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn
main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181) [INFO] Opening socket connection to
server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to
authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-10-11 17:26:20.881 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn
main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181) [INFO] Socket connection established
to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
2017-10-11 17:26:20.932 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn
main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181) [INFO] Session establishment complete
on server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid =
0x15f0d3b46a70017, negotiated timeout = 20000
2017-10-11 17:26:20.933 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager
main-EventThread [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2017-10-11 17:26:20.952 o.a.s.l.Localizer main [INFO] Reconstruct localized
resource: C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\storm-local\supervisor\usercache
2017-10-11 17:26:20.954 o.a.s.l.Localizer main [WARN] No left over
resources found for any user during reconstructing of local resources at:
C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\storm-local\supervisor\usercache
2017-10-11 17:26:20.962 o.a.s.d.s.Supervisor main [INFO] Starting
supervisor for storm version '1.1.1'.
2017-10-11 17:26:21.005 o.a.s.d.s.Slot main [WARN] SLOT [MY PC NAME]:6700
Starting in state EMPTY - assignment null
2017-10-11 17:26:21.006 o.a.s.d.s.Slot main [WARN] SLOT [MY PC NAME]:6701
Starting in state EMPTY - assignment null
2017-10-11 17:26:21.006 o.a.s.d.s.Slot main [WARN] SLOT [MY PC NAME]:6701
Starting in state EMPTY - assignment null
2017-10-11 17:26:21.009 o.a.s.d.s.Slot main [WARN] SLOT [MY PC NAME]:6703
Starting in state EMPTY - assignment null
2017-10-11 17:26:21.020 o.a.s.d.s.Container main [INFO] GET worker-user for
964b34c1-d7e3-4f22-9ee2-a0664c10294e
2017-10-11 17:26:21.022 o.a.s.d.s.Container main [INFO] Cleaning up
5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539:964b34c1-d7e3-4f22-9ee2-a0664c10294e
2017-10-11 17:26:21.023 o.a.s.d.s.Container main [INFO] GET worker-user for
964b34c1-d7e3-4f22-9ee2-a0664c10294e
2017-10-11 17:26:21.024 o.a.s.d.s.AdvancedFSOps main [INFO] Deleting path
C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\storm-local\workers\964b34c1-d7e3-4f22-9ee2-a0664c10294e\heartbeats
2017-10-11 17:26:21.029 o.a.s.d.s.AdvancedFSOps main [INFO] Deleting path
C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\storm-local\workers\964b34c1-d7e3-4f22-9ee2-a0664c10294e\pids
2017-10-11 17:26:21.032 o.a.s.d.s.AdvancedFSOps main [INFO] Deleting path
C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\storm-local\workers\964b34c1-d7e3-4f22-9ee2-a0664c10294e\tmp
2017-10-11 17:26:21.034 o.a.s.d.s.AdvancedFSOps main [INFO] Deleting path
C:\apache-storm-1.1.1\storm-local\workers\964b34c1-d7e3-4f22-9ee2-a0664c10294e
```

here are my Nimbus logs at the same time:

```
2017-10-11 17:26:22.189 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:[2 2] not alive
2017-10-11 17:26:22.189 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:[3 3] not alive
2017-10-11 17:26:22.189 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:[1 1] not alive
2017-10-11 17:26:22.189 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:[4 4] not alive
2017-10-11 17:26:22.190 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
kafkaTopology-1-1507755826:[2 2] not alive
2017-10-11 17:26:22.190 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
kafkaTopology-1-1507755826:[3 3] not alive
2017-10-11 17:26:22.190 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
kafkaTopology-1-1507755826:[1 1] not alive
2017-10-11 17:26:22.192 o.a.s.s.EvenScheduler timer [INFO] Available slots:
(["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6700]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6701]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6702]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6703])
2017-10-11 17:26:22.192 o.a.s.s.EvenScheduler timer [INFO] Available slots:
(["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6701]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6702]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6703])
2017-10-11 17:26:22.195 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Setting new assignment
for topology id storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:
#org.apache.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "storm-local",
:node->host {"5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" "
LNAR-PC0611K6.corp.capgemini.com"}, :executor->node+port {[4 4]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6701], [3 3]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6701], [2 2]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6701], [1 1]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6701]}, :executor->start-time-secs
{[1 1] 1507757182, [2 2] 1507757182, [3 3] 1507757182, [4 4] 1507757182},
:worker->resources {["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6701] [0.0 0.0
0.0]}, :owner "rbliton"}
2017-10-11 17:26:22.201 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Setting new assignment
for topology id kafkaTopology-1-1507755826:
#org.apache.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "storm-local",
:node->host {"5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" "
LNAR-PC0611K6.corp.capgemini.com"}, :executor->node+port {[2 2]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6700], [1 1]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6700], [3 3]
["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6700]}, :executor->start-time-secs
{[1 1] 1507757182, [2 2] 1507757182, [3 3] 1507757182}, :worker->resources
{["5ef774ff-f24c-4810-9330-5e1291bd7539" 6700] [0.0 0.0 0.0]}, :owner
"rbliton"}
2017-10-11 17:26:23.209 o.a.s.d.nimbus pool-14-thread-25 [INFO] Created
download session for kafkaTopology-1-1507755826-stormjar.jar with id
bed36ea8-1d05-4d80-8006-c2bfb40ed8f6
2017-10-11 17:26:23.801 o.a.s.d.nimbus pool-14-thread-7 [INFO] Created
download session for kafkaTopology-1-1507755826-stormcode.ser with id
7227688a-4381-48d5-ac27-c6a6e03f5a5d
2017-10-11 17:26:23.837 o.a.s.d.nimbus pool-14-thread-11 [INFO] Created
download session for kafkaTopology-1-1507755826-stormconf.ser with id
d4d6712b-55ec-46fe-8e9c-6df068d65133
2017-10-11 17:26:23.913 o.a.s.d.nimbus pool-14-thread-20 [INFO] Created
download session for storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303-stormjar.jar with
id 3b7263a0-fd39-4caf-b90b-3deaf3999308
2017-10-11 17:26:24.496 o.a.s.d.nimbus pool-14-thread-64 [INFO] Created
download session for storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303-stormcode.ser with
id cd88098a-22c7-44c3-b709-34a202bc4952
2017-10-11 17:26:24.529 o.a.s.d.nimbus pool-14-thread-63 [INFO] Created
download session for storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303-stormconf.ser with
id e7478249-7082-4edb-93bb-3746f39db06e
2017-10-11 17:28:29.931 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:[2 2] not alive
2017-10-11 17:28:29.931 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:[3 3] not alive
2017-10-11 17:28:29.931 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:[1 1] not alive
2017-10-11 17:28:29.932 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:[4 4] not alive
2017-10-11 17:28:29.932 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
kafkaTopology-1-1507755826:[2 2] not alive
2017-10-11 17:28:29.932 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
kafkaTopology-1-1507755826:[3 3] not alive
2017-10-11 17:28:29.932 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Executor
kafkaTopology-1-1507755826:[1 1] not alive
2017-10-11 17:28:29.936 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Setting new assignment
for topology id storm-kafka-topology1-2-1507756303:
#org.apache.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "storm-local",
:node->host {}, :executor->node+port {}, :executor->start-time-secs {[1 1]
1507757182, [2 2] 1507757182, [3 3] 1507757182, [4 4] 1507757182},
:worker->resources {}, :owner "rbliton"}
2017-10-11 17:28:29.943 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Setting new assignment
for topology id kafkaTopology-1-1507755826:
#org.apache.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "storm-local",
:node->host {}, :executor->node+port {}, :executor->start-time-secs {[1 1]
1507757182, [2 2] 1507757182, [3 3] 1507757182}, :worker->resources {},
:owner "rbliton"}
```